# strtotime weird behaviour when - sign in offset

Tags: php, strtotime

From the below line -

```
$date = strtotime('-' . (-100) . ' years');
```

I get a value `4654765319` when I try this on my local code. Same line gives a value of `$date` as `NULL` when tried on a live site. This line doesn't include any variables so there's no point of other code affecting it.

I get a correct value in both local and live if I remove the minus sign -i.e

```
$date = strtotime('-' . (100) . ' years');
```

gives the same output `-1656664323` on both cases.

Can anyone make out why `strtotime()` is behaving differently on two platforms with `-` symbol?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the same PHP versions?

Comment: yes, thanks for asking, both are on  5.6.30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely, you are running a 32-bit version of PHP. Note from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes):

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)

You can instead use PHP's `DateTime` class:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('-' . (-100) . ' years');

echo $date->format('U');
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/826626)

Here's a clear reproduction of the issue:

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/826663)

Comment: Ah, eval.in is using 32, I was testing on 3v4l and wasn't reproducing there. Might want to show the issue is reproducible on eval (https://eval.in/826641) and this does resolve it.

Comment: Excellent - Thanks for answering.

Comment: @chris85 Good idea, edited. No problem jitendrapurohit

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '-' . (-100) . ' years'."\n";
echo '-' . (100) . ' years'."\n";
```

will print out

```
--100 years
-100 years
```

The first one is clearly a bad date string, the [strtotime man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) says the function will return `FALSE` as a result, which will look like `NULL`, so your live site is working correctly.  I don't know why your local machine would not give the same result - compare the configurations between the two machines - are they running the same O/S and version?

After George made his commment below, I wrote a more complete test program on my 64-bit machine:

```
<?php
echo '-' . (-100) . ' years'."\n";
echo '-' . (100) . ' years'."\n";
echo ($d1=strtotime('-' . (-100) . ' years'))."\n";
echo ($d2=strtotime('-' . (100) . ' years'))."\n";
echo date('Y-m-d',$d1)."\n";
echo date('Y-m-d',$d2)."\n";
```

which printed out

```
--100 years
-100 years
4654771244
-1656662356
2117-07-03
1917-07-03
```

I had never tried it before, but apparently `strtotime()` interprets `--100` as `-(-100)` which is `+100` - so I'm going to say your *live* site is the one that's not working correctly, probably because it's a 32 bit environment.

Comment: While your idea is correct, [`strtotime()` has no problem handling `--` values.](https://eval.in/826639)